# Where would the on-load handler be in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, onload

I'm looking to add code to my Onload handler but am unsure where it would be in an MVC application?

```
 // You may want to place these lines inside an onload handler
 CFInstall.check({
     mode: "overlay",
     destination: "http://localhost:1414/"
 });
});
```

The code above needs to be placed in the onload handler.

Comment: in mvc u can use controller method in that the firest default method is index you can use it

Comment: Is that javascript? Javascript isn't anything special in MVC, it works just like javascript in html.

Answer (score 12):

If I understand you correctly, you just need this expression below, if you are using jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Handler for .ready() called. Put your logic here.
    });
</script>
```

or this one, without usage of jQuery:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        // Put your logic here.        
    } 
</script>
```

to be included on your view.cshtml.

Comment: window.onload  and  $(document).ready(function() {
        
    });  has so much difference .

Answer (score 1):

Here your meaning Adding **Window Onload Event.**

You can try this **inside the js file:**

```
function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

addLoadEvent(nameOfSomeFunctionToRunOnPageLoad);

addLoadEvent(function() {
  /* more code to run on page load */ 
});
```

***For more information*** [Simon Willison’s Weblog](http://simonwillison.net/2004/May/26/addLoadEvent/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add it just like in any other html page into your cshtml..

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Authenticate";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        CFInstall.check({
            mode: "overlay",
            destination: "http://localhost:1414/"
        });
    });
</script>
<h2>Congrats..</h2>
```